# FQL comment table parent_id column doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments, parent-child, parent

In the Graph API Explorer this query give me results

```
SELECT post_id, fromid, text, time, id, username, likes, user_likes, parent_id FROM comment WHERE post_id = '100940606645739_405463442860119' ORDER BY time DESC
```

BUT, when I try to make the call from my aplication:

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT post_id, fromid, text, time, id, username, likes, user_likes, parent_id FROM comment WHERE post_id = '100940606645739_405463442860119' ORDER BY time DESC&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

(The last link also works in the Graph API Explorer)

It says that parent_id is not a member of the comment table.

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#602) parent_id is not a member of the comment table.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 602
   }
}
```

This is a Facebook error??

***NOTE:** never share your facebook secret or access tokens.*

Answer (score 0):

**Refer to bug at:**

Comments from threaded posts not showing up in API

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/555752071131751?browse=search_5175ab4f32aa87763025618

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem initially as well, but fixed it by simply enabling the July 2013 Migration for my app.

Hope this helps.